# How does the zero account transfer tokens?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, transactions

In [this transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x1239ff2fdc42a5c197ec006734339f31e77d69e2108037b09f534634b5d36e37), the from address is withdrawing Dai from the Compound contract.

What puzzles me is why the zero address(`0x00`...) can transfer Dai to the from address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**According to your link to etherscan, the transaction is:**

```
From: 0x2b9c37a4a6f27a95a790a9935a998123167425f0
To: Contract 0x5d3a536e4d6dbd6114cc1ead35777bab948e3643
```

**And the method invoked on that contract is:**

```
Function: redeem(uint256 redeemTokens)
```

This function calls another function and so on, but the important part is that at some point during the transaction, two ERC20-standard `Transfer` events are emitted.

**Here is the definition of the ERC20-standard `Transfer` event:**

```
event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value);
```

I'm not sure whether or not this is dictated by the standard, but in either case, it is custom to use:

- `_from = 0x00000000000000000000...` when minting new tokens
- `_to = 0x00000000000000000000...` when burning existing tokens

And when both are non-zero, the event "finally" signifies a transfer of tokens from one address to another (this one IS dictated by the standard for sure).

In any case, etherscan knows all of that, and displays ERC20 transfer information accordingly.

**In the transaction that you've linked in your question, it is:**

1. From `0x00000000000000000000...` To `0x2b9c37a4a6f27a95a790...`
2. From `0x2b9c37a4a6f27a95a790...` To Compound Dai

The 1st one is the minting of new tokens for `0x2b9c37a4a6f27a95a790...`.

The 2nd one is the transferring of tokens from `0x2b9c37a4a6f27a95a790...` to Compound Dai.

So to answer your question in short, the **transaction** is not sent from `0x00000000000000000000...`.